# Powershell Du.exe Error

Tags: powershell

I am using DU.exe in Powershell script to capture the size of a remote folder, code as below:

```
$Duexe ="c:\du\du.exe"

$unc = "\\$server\$Letter$\$Name"

write-host "Processing:  " $unc

$stuff =  du -q "\\$server\$Letter$\$Name" 2>&1 

$formated = $stuff | Format-Table -auto

write-host $stuff
```

I have to redirect the stderror to stop an error caused by the "-q" switch.  However the output contians following error:

```
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException

In context:

Files:        290215 Directories:  2246 Size:         128,529,542,967 bytes Size on disk: 128,529,542,967 bytes  System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
```

Why is this?  If I run du outside powershell I get no errors on the same unc paths.

Comment: I have just found out if I trun of the stderror redirect it does nto display the messgae howevere it does display:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't so much stop the error as "redirect" the error to the output stream which you captured in the variable `$stuff`. Try redirecting just the error stream to `$null` to ignore it:

```
$stuff =  du -q "\\$server\$Letter$\$Name" 2> $null

$stuff | Format-Table -auto
```

BTW, you don't need to write-host the "formatted" stuff.  Format-Table will output to the host automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You don't redirect output in Powershell with Batch style `>`. Just use `$stuff = du -q $unc` to get the `du` output into a variable.

By the way, you print `$stuff` but set formatted content into `$formated`. Is this intended?